# Flask reroute always using default function argument

Tags: flask, routes

Given a route such as the one below, I have found that if I have a default value for the argument **test** it won't change when passing a value via **url_for** with a **redirect**. What I'd like is to change the parameter **test** when rendering the template, depending on whether a form was just submitted or not.

```
@app.route('/view_story/<story_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_story(story_id, test='no'):
    ...
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            #Add stuff to database from the form. 
            return redirect(url_for('view_story', story_id=story_id, test='yes'))

    return render_template('story.html', test=test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```py
@app.route('/view_story/<story_id>', defaults={"test": "no"})
@app.route('/view_story/<story_id>/<test>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_story(story_id, test):
    ...
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            #Add stuff to database from the form. 
            return redirect(url_for('view_story', story_id=story_id, test='yes'))

    return render_template('story.html', test=test)
```

Comment: @fuzzylogical, if you feel that this clarified you question, please upvote/accept the answer.